# Correct optargs handling of non-optional parameters (c)

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I have a program that needs to be called using:

```
program parameter1 parameter2 -x1 -y
```

but I feel that it should work if I do:

```
program -x1 -y parameter1 parameter2
```

or combinations thereof. How do I get `parameter1` and `parameter2` without a horrid dirty hack? At the moment I have a

```
while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "x:y")) != -1){
   /* do stuff */
}
```

loop for the optional arguments, but what about the others? It would seem wrong to just look at `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` because they could be anywhere.

I'm sure there is an established solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you exit the `while` loop, `optind` points to the first non-option argument.  Take a look at the `getopt(3)` man page:

```
   If  there  are  no  more option characters, getopt() returns -1.  Then optind is the
   index in argv of the first argv-element that is not an option.
```

So your first non-option argument is `argv[optind]` and so forth.

```
while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "x:y")) != -1){
   /* do stuff */
} 

param1 = argv[optind]
param2 = argv[optind+1]
```

`getopt` will permute the arguments so that this will still be true even for your first example, where the option arguments are on the command line after the non-option arguments.